# How to create a responsive div where inside it have a squre and some texts

Tags: html, css

Below i write the code, in this code i want to make responsive 'rectangle' and 'square' and i also want to make resopnsive text in the p tag.

```css
#rectangle
{
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: brown;
}
#square
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: chocolate;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">
   <div id="square">

   </div>

   <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, iusto. Sapiente fugiat illo 
      dolorum assumenda commodi!
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: this question is too board, what kind of response do you want?

Comment: In this question i want to ask that how i create outer div which id has 'rectangle' and inner div which id has 'square' responsive

Answer (score 0):

For the widths and heights, use `%` instead of `px`. For the text, add an id or class that defines a font using the `vw` unit. For example:

```
<div id="rectangle">
  <div id="square">

  </div>
  <p id='text'>
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, iusto. Sapiente 
    fugiat illo dolorum assumenda commodi!
  </p>
</div>
```

```
#rectangle
{
    background-color: brown;
    display: flex;
    height: 8%;
    position: relative;
    width: 10%;
}
#square
{
    background-color: chocolate;
    height: 8%;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 10%;
}
#text
{
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. If you want responsiveness, use `%` or `vh / vw`

```css
#rectangle
{
    display: flex;
    width: 70vw;
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: brown;
    font-size: 2.3vw;
}
#square
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: chocolate;
    margin-right: 3%;
     display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.arrow-up {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 10vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 10vw solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10vw solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">
   <div id="square">
    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
   </div>

   <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, iusto. Sapiente fugiat illo 
      dolorum assumenda commodi!
   </p>
</div>
```